# lamp: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying

Tags: apache, symfony, vagrant, virtualbox, lamp

I created an Ubuntu vhost, it's my virtual server for current project. Since I'm using symfony I downloaded composer, apache and etc. While doing this everything worked just fine. So at the last step, I configured `/etc/apache2/available-sites/000-default.conf` file and set new path for my project. After that I did `vagrant reload`. Since when my problem occurred. While booting virtual machine I'm getting such an error:

> lamp: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
>       lamp: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
>       lamp: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
>       lamp: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...

Why is it happening? Where should I look, to fix this error?

My Vagrant file:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
config.vm.box = "precise32"
# Mentioning the SSH Username/Password:
config.ssh.username = "vagrant"
config.ssh.password = "vagrant"
# Begin Configuring
config.vm.define "lamp" do|lamp|
lamp.vm.hostname = "lamp" # Setting up hostname
lamp.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.205.10" # Setting up machine's IP Address
lamp.vm.provision :shell, path: "script.sh" # Provisioning with script.sh
end
# End Configuring
end
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I already tried some solutions:
My Hyper-v is disabled.
VM gui is enabled.

**EDIT 2**

After some research I realized that command `vagrant reload` is causing this error. Still looking for solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see that message a few times it's normal. Vagrant is trying to connect to the VM while it is still booting, so it fails. But in the end you should see a success message, in that case everything is fine and you have nothing wrong on your machine.

P.S. "vagrant reload" only means to turn off the VM and turn it on again. So it cannot really be the cause of any problem; you probably see the same message when you dou "vagrant halt" and then "vagrant up".

Comment: I think my vagrant stucks somewhere on command vagrant reload. I did load of tests and I'm sure. probobly my os is causing it.

Comment: So just to be sure: everytime you do "vagrant reload" you see the error, but if you do "vagrant halt" and then "vagrant up" you do no?

Comment: I can't explain what happened but past few weeks vagrant was working without any freezes. What I did is I re-installed vagrant virtual box. Thanks